# How to check the value of the currently selected option (using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, dom

I'm having an issue finding the value of the currently selected option.

Heres what I have tried so far...

```js
const status = document.getElementById("task-status");
let value = status.options[status.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(value);
```

```html
<label for="task-status">Status</label>
<select class="form-control" id="task-status" required>
  <option selected disabled value="">Select status</option>
  <option value="to do">To Do</option>
  <option value="review">Review</option>
  <option value="in progress">In Progress</option>
  <option value="done">Done</option>
</select>
```

This prints nothing to the console and have no idea why.

What I want to do ultimately is check if the user selected option has a value of "" (empty)
if so, display error (selection invalid).
Otherwise if the user selected option is !"" (not empty)
the selection is valid

It might be worth noting that I'm using Bootstrap and its forms. Not sure if that could have an effect.

I have tried searching for solutions for hours so I'd really appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you

Comment: Your code works as it is, but the selected option has an empty string as its value. If you need the value when a new option has been selected, then you need to listen [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) on the select element.

Comment: Oh, I see, let me take a look into that and get back to you. 

I did hardcode the select options so that one of them (not the default one) had the 'selected' attribute and that still retuned an empty string.

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://jsfiddle.net/c5a8z3Ld/), but this is run only when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

It just simple `var x = document.getElementById("task-status").value;` , check more at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp

Comment: I have tried this too, but this always returns an empty string.

Comment: you try logging variable "status" to check more info

Comment: Yes, I have just tried that and it returns the select element as expected.

Comment: what is value of status.value at inspected object in console?

Answer (score 0):

You can create and `eventListener` to check the value whenever a change is detected on the dropdown value.

https://jsfiddle.net/hxo8a5dt/

```
const status = document.getElementById("task-status");
status.addEventListener("change", function(event){console.log(event.target.value)});
```

With all event listeners the event is automatically passed to the function which you can reference and check for the value.

Also check `console.log(event)` and have a look at all the other goodies it holds :)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't print anything to the console. 

I'm so confused as everything I've tried doesn't seem to return the currently selected option

Comment: Will you create a fiddle with your code? If you check my fiddle you'll see that the value is printed when you select an option.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you only need to use the `value` but there are times when you want to find the text and the value so `.options.selectedIndex` provides that possibility as below.

```js
const oSel=document.getElementById("task-status")

oSel.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  let value=this.value;
  let optval=oSel.options[oSel.options.selectedIndex].value;
  let opttext=oSel.options[oSel.options.selectedIndex].text;
  
  console.info('%s - %s - %s', value,optval,opttext);
});
```

```html
<label for="task-status">Status</label>
<select class="form-control" id="task-status" required>
  <option selected disabled hidden>Select status
  <option value="to do">To Do!
  <option value="review">Review!
  <option value="in progress">In Progress!
  <option value="done">Done
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to show me this, I will give that a try. 

I’ve only been doing JavaScript for a couple of weeks so I’m sure it’s a simple fix, I’m just not quite competent at debugging and finding the solution just yet. 

I’ll get back to you when I’ve tried your solution. I think I understand what you have done here...